# Is there an enaml widget to display a table?

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, pandas, dataframe, enaml

I would like to display a (numeric and/or textual) table inside a Python GUI built with enaml, but surprisingly there seem to be no enaml widget for that.

Some years ago, [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/enaml/soUKRvXT_BU), they said there would have been some developments in that direction, but nothing followed.

More recently, [here](https://github.com/enthought/traits-enaml/blob/update-data-frame-table/traits_enaml/widgets/data_frame_table.py), they provided an enaml widget for displaying a pandas dataframe (that would also be OK for the task) but it does not seem to work with the latest version of traits_enaml (I get an error message from traits_enaml.utils: 'cannot import name get_unicode_string').

So the question is: Does anybody know of a table widget for enaml? For this (very useful, I'd say) widget are you forced to abandon enaml and resort to traditional imperative GUI frameworks?

I am a newbie, so I apologize beforehand for errors or a missed straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use RawWidget to use your own Qt TableView or have a look at an implementation here: https://github.com/frmdstryr/enamlx